# ContentDialog behavior difference with Creators Update

Tags: dialog, uwp-xaml, creators-update

I have a scenario where I change the size of a content dialog in the view model. This works fine in the AnniversaryUpdate, but with the Creators Update, I get a totally different (and unworkable) behavior.

I have a content dialog where I want to change the screen size from portrait to landscape based on user input. In build 14393 (anniversary) it works just fine. When I toggle the project to use the Creators Update (150630) it does not work at all.

Here is the XAML code driving the issue:

```
<ContentDialog
x:Class="DialogView"
...snip...
Background="LightGray"
MinHeight="{Binding GridHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding GridWidth}">

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid Background="AliceBlue" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Button Content="{Binding Orientation}" Height="40" Click="ToggleButton_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</Grid>
```

When I run built for the Creators Update, I get a very small dialog that will not change size.

Answer (score 0):

The default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog in 14393 is different from the default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog in 15063.

In the default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog in 15063, it use `ContentDialogMinHeight` and `ContentDialogMinWidth` to set the `MinHeight` and `MinWidth`. And the default value of `ContentDialogMinHeight` and `ContentDialogMinWidth` are 184 and 320.

When you set the value to `MinHeight` and `MinWidth` property in the `ContentDialog` control, it will not change the value that define in the style.

In 14393, it does not define the `MinHeight` and `MinWidth` in the default style.  If you want to get the same `MinHeight` and `MinWidth` as 14393 in 15063, you should be able to copy the default style in 15063 and remove the following code:

```
<Setter Property = "MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMinHeight}" />
<Setter Property = "MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMinWidth}" />
```